# Setting Initial Offsets for New Kafka Partitions in Consumer Groups

Tags: apache-kafka

When a new partition is added to a Kafka topic, the offset for this partition in a consumer group isn't initially set in the Kafka broker. Typically, the offset is determined based on `auto.offset.reset` when the consumer group detects the new partition. This setup is beneficial for scenarios where starting consumption from the start or the latest offset is needed due to offset corruption or other issues.

However, a challenge arises when a new partition is added, and the consumer doesn't detect it promptly. Messages accumulate in this partition, and when the consumer eventually starts consuming, using `auto.offset.reset = latest`, it might miss the original messages.

Is there a method or configuration to set the initial offset for all consumer groups of the topic to 0 when a new partition is created? This would allow for consistent handling of new partitions and prevent missing original messages when the consumer eventually starts consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a consumer in the group, then use commitSync for that new TopicPartition, for whichever offsets you want to store

Otherwise, seek API always works, too.

If you're setting auto.offset.reset=latest, anyway, you're explicitly accepting that your app doesn't care about any existing data